# Occasional 'Access to XMLHttpRequest' on large put requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

**UPDATE:**

**Increase `client_max_body_size` NGINX configuration file**

As @sideshowbarker suggested, Firefox showed the real reason why the call was failing - `413 Request Entity Too Large` in nginx. Since node had already a max limit of '50mb', the limit had to be increased on the server itself, which fixed the problem.

[link to the question on how to update nginx](https://serverfault.com/questions/814767/413-request-entity-too-large-in-nginx-with-client-max-body-size-set)

---

Have been stuck on this for some time now. Any help will be appreciated.

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://a.com' from origin 'https://b.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

I receive CORS error which happens occasionally only on some large PUT requests which include inline svg. Can not replicate on localhost. 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on `a.com` and the call goes through successfully with smaller svgs or any other calls.

Also, there is already an increased bodyParser.json limit (up to 50 mb).

This is what `a.com` script looks like:

```js
const allowedOrigins = [
  'https://b.com',
  'http://localhost.b.com'
];

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  const origin = req.headers.origin;
  if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1) {
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', origin);
  }
  next();
});

app.use(express.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(
  express.urlencoded({
    limit: '50mb',
    extended: true,
    parameterLimit: 50000
  })
);

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods',
    'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,PATCH,OPTIONS'
  );
  res.header(
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers',
    'authorization, content-type, date, cache-control, content-length, pragma, server, status'
  );
  next();
});

app.use('/api', routes);
```

[image]

Comment: If the problem really is with the body parser, try moving the middleware that sends the CORS headers before it.

Comment: It may be a problem with the timing between the preflight request and the PUT request. Typically a preflight authorizes for the next request made, but there's often a time limit put on it. If the next request doesn't happen within N seconds of the preflight, the next request is refused. Unfortunately, I can't remember where I read that...

Comment: @Bergi just tried moving it on top as you suggested but unfortunately didn't help

Comment: @HereticMonkey hmm never heard about it but going to google now

Comment: When you get that CORS error, what’s the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. If Chrome doesn’t seem to show it to you, use the Network in Firefox. Is it a 413 or other 4xx or 5xx error rather a a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker chrome doesn't show anything but firefox shows `413 Request Entity Too Large`. which means the issue is with the payload. however I believe 50mb for body parser is the max or am I wrong?

Comment: I don’t know about what the Node limits might be, but given that the response is a 413 error, at least you can safely rule out CORS as having anything to do with the cause. The only reason the browser logs a CORS error in this case is that 4xx errors typically aren’t going to have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header. That’s expected. And even if a 413 error did have the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header, it’d still be an error that needed fixing. Anyway, given that you now know it’s a 413 error, you might want to retitle and update the question to make that clear.

Comment: @sideshowbarker thank you for your help!